# Gurobi or CPLEX? Quadratic indefinite objective - quadratic positive-semidefinite constraints

Tags: cplex, gurobi, quadratic-programming, non-convex

I want to minimize a quadratic objective function subject to a set of linear and quadratic constraints.

The quadratic objective function is indefinite (non-convex). The quadratic constraints are positive-semidefinite (convex).
The variables are continuous.

Can I handle this with Gurobi or CPLEX? Which one is the better choice?

Answer (score 3):

Gurobi handles convex problems only. Cplex can handle convex problems and certain classes of non-convex problems.

Cplex has an `OptimalityTarget` parameter to select the non-convex solver. Unfortunately it only supports QP and MIQP problems (i.e. only linear constraints).

Other global solvers you can try are [Baron](http://archimedes.cheme.cmu.edu/?q=baron), [GloMIQO](http://helios.princeton.edu/GloMIQO/), or [Couenne](https://projects.coin-or.org/Couenne).

Comment: But Cplex is in general able to handle quadratic constraints. Do you mean that Cplex cannot deal with quadratic constraints in this special case as the objective function is non-convex?

Comment: No, you are mistaken in your first statement. Cplex cannot handle general quadratic constraints. It can only handle convex quadratic constraints (with either a linear or convex quadratic objective). 

Again, Cplex only supports a non-convex quadratic objective if the constraints are linear. Please consult the Cplex documentation for further information.